# How can I use grep to search a file for string combinations?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

What I'm trying to do is use grep to search my Apache logs. What I want is to find is every entry from a certain IP address that also has .html or .php in the line. In other words, I want to see what pages they've accessed without all of the Javascript, CSS, and images included.

I know I can search for the lines with the IP address with `grep '123.123.123.123' logfile` but how I can add to the pattern so that it will only match lines that include the IP address, and '.php' or '.html'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep '123\.123\.123\.123.*\(\.php\|\.html\)' logfile
```

Unless of course the `.php` or `.html` precedes the IP address:

```
grep '\(\.php\|\.html\).*123\.123\.123\.123' logfile
```

You can always craft a regex that does both, but a simple option is just to use two greps:

```
grep '123\.123\.123\.123' logfile | grep '\.php\|\.html'
```

Note the `\.` which I originally forgot matches an actual dot, while a dot on its own matches any character. It may be easier to omit the `\` since it is easier to type and unlikely to cause problems. Also `grep -F`, as with Hauke's answer will match fixed strings, no need for `\` there. `grep -E` can also be used to enable extended expressions, meaning the `\` before each parenthesis or the `|` should be omitted.

Comment: Note that `grep -E '(a|b)'` is standard and portable but `grep '\(a\|b\)'` is not.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 123.123.123.123 foo.html | grep -E '123\.123\.123\.123.*\.(php|html)'
```

or, maybe faster

```
echo 123.123.123.123 foo.html | grep -F 123.123.123.123 | \
  grep -F -e .php -e .html
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the two searches together:

```
grep '123\.123\.123\.123' whatever.log | grep -P "php|html"
```

The first `grep` picks lines with the ip, then the second one filters those for lines that contain "php" or "html".

Note that for this to work you need a PCRE capable grep (hence `-P` switch in the 2nd `grep`).  Graeme's answer contains a variant that doesn't rely on this.

Comment: `cat`, really...?

Comment: @HaukeLaging : Tch, point taken :)